# What is the correct way to fetch Command inside Contract class

Tags: corda

1. Kindly explain the difference between the below two codding snippets, both are fetching the command value but in different ways. Which is the standard way to fetch the command in the Contract class?

   ```
   final CommandData command = tx.getCommand(0).getValue();

   final CommandWithParties<Commands> command = requireSingleCommand(tx.getCommands(), Commands.class);
   final Commands commandData = command.getValue();
   ```
2. What is the benefit of using **TypeOnlyCommandData**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The typical approach to define commands can be seen in the [IOU example](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/62722858a2f50512a9445e1f79b4619d2e8199d0/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/contract/IOUContract.java#L57-L62):

```java
public interface Commands extends CommandData {
    class Create implements Commands {}
}
```

2. Notice that the IOU example uses [requireSingleCommand()](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/62722858a2f50512a9445e1f79b4619d2e8199d0/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/contract/IOUContract.java#L36) because it expects that the transaction will have only one command; otherwise it will throw an error.
   So if you are creating a transaction that has multiple types of states, you cannot use the above function; because the transaction will have multiple commands (one per each state type), instead you can extract the commands that are related to your state type (see example [here](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/5f189fbf54c400343729155a856b99ed91d40da8/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/contracts/AbstractTokenContract.kt#L102-L103)); then do the verification against them.